# JSON property trees with restclient-cpp

Tags: c++, json, boost

I am trying to use Boost to do some computation on JSON arrays, my question is the following:

How can I make a rest call (using something like rest-client-cpp) to populate the Ptree with JSON data instead of using a file.

Here is what I have so far:

```
namespace pt = boost::property_tree;
pt::ptree root;
pt::read_json("filename.json", root);
```

I want to replace the "filename.json" with JSON brought in through a GET request. Below is an example rest call when using "rest-client-cpp"

```
RestClient::response r = RestClient::get("http://urlhere.com");
```

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use version of [read_json](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/property_tree/reference.html#header.boost.property_tree.json_parser_hpp), that receives `istream`. You should create [std::istringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and store contents of response in it.

```
RestClient::response r = RestClient::get("http://urlhere.com");
std::istreamstream stream(r.body);
pt::ptree root;
pt::read_json(stream, root);
```

Comment: this looks like it would work (although very inefficiently) assuming https://github.com/mrtazz/restclient-cpp/blob/master/include/restclient-cpp/restclient.h. Considering using `boost::iostreams::array_source` or similar to avoid the copying. (Boost Interprocess may also have a `stringstream` replacement that avoids the copy, IIRC)

Answer (score 0):

You can call read_json with a `std::istream` instead of a filename.

Comment: How would I set that up on top of pt::?

Comment: It depends. Which `RestClient` class do you use? If it doesn't give you an `std::istream`, then you can try with a `std::istringstream`, just as @ForEveR has suggested.